# What permissions does schtasks.exe need to query another server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task

I've got a Server 2012 machine, HostA, and a Windows 7 machine, MONITOR_VM, both on our domain. HostA is running a scheduled task. I want to query the info for this task from MONITOR_VM. I'm using this command:

```
schtasks.exe /query /S HostA /TN "taskname" /v /fo list
```

When I run it as myself (who is an Admin on HostA) from MONITOR_VM, it works just fine. When I run it as DOMAIN\UserX (which is the lower-privilege user my batch script will be running as) from MONITOR_VM, it keeps saying "Access is denied." I'm trying to figure out what permissions I need to grant UserX so it can get access.

I've tried giving UserX Full Control to `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` on HostA, but it didn't change anything. I know it's not a firewall issue since I myself can run the query just fine (we're using a hardware firewall, not Windows Firewall, and the two are not fighting, Windows Firewall is off.)

Comment: I have read that in 2008R2 `schtasks.exe` used to access remote filesystem via `c$` share, which is admin-only. Not sure about how it's done in 2012R2. I think it uses WMI, so the user needs some WMI access (no data about namespace). I say run procmon from sysinternals to find out what does the process try to access, and what level is required.